# Regex ISSUE - can't match a URL that ends with nothing

Tags: regex, url, matching

Hey guys. I', trying to have a regex made up to match all URL's like these:

1. http://example.com
2. http://example.com/
3. http://example.com/index.html
4. http://example.com/index
5. http://example.com/index/
6. http://www.example.com
7. http://www.example.com/
8. http://www.example.com/index.html
9. http://www.example.com/index
10. http://www.example.com/index/

and to match URLs that have ' # ' or ' ? ' only until the character before those 2 ones.
This way 
http://example.com/index.php?p=Hey -> http://example.com/index.php

The regex code I have so far works well when selecting only certain file types or a folder except one case:

- if I have an URL that does not end with either a file extension (eg: .html, .php) or a folder (eg: /) the pattern will not match properly as some URLs (eg: http://example.com/about-me) will be excluded.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks everyone.

---

This is the regex:

```
^(?<protocol>http(s?))://(?<domain>[^/\r\n#?]+)(?<path>/[^?#]*(?:html|php|/))?
```

Comment: Do you just want to remove everything starting from `?` or `#` from the URLs?

Comment: Basically yes.. and every URL is ok but the one ending with nothing. This is because there are for instance the WordPress URLs:
- http://myblog.com/about-me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language you're using, but regular expressions may not be necessary for this if you've got a list of URLs already.

In C#, you could do something like this:

```
string a = "http://example.com/index.php?p=Hey";
string b = a.Remove(a.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'?', '#'}, 0));
```

Comment: You do have a point.. I'm using PHP. I was thinking of also checking the URL for validity with one trip but the code above does not do that so I might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want:

```
^(?<protocol>http(s?))://(?<domain>[^/\s#?]+)(?<path>/[^\s#?]*)?(?<query>.*)?
```

The query will contain the rest that you might want to ignore.

Comment: Almost corect.. I think I forgot to mention above that I also need to scan (this whole thing is for a little crawler) only certain pages like (html|php|/) or folders. That is why the issue occured.

Comment: Well, you can not determine if a URL ending with `/` or ending without any special character is a folder or not. `http://example.com/about-me` can be a folder or a file, you can not tell.... Most webservers handle folder paths without trailing `/`

Comment: Actually in a URL something like folder does not really exist. Everything that a webserver serves is files, some might have listings to other files, but you can not determine that before you actually look at the file.